# request using VBA with JSON response

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am coding through VBA-WEB, VBA-REST, etc. I refer to VBA and coding related homepage.

https://www.marketscreener.com

I think I should have a COOKIE value after signing in and logging into my homepage.

https://www.marketscreener.com/stock-exchange/shares/North-America-8/United-States-12/

I would like to import the data values ​​from the image below into Excel.

Lists of companies belonging to category[ Company/Price/Capitalization/1st Jan% Sector]

I've been working hard with VBA-WEB, VBA-REST..BUT..
 
0 # - #

Only these results are displayed. I did not know what was wrong, so I got a request.
It is a level that only VBA is learned very little because it does not know because it is a coding starter.

Sheets (1) .Cells (2, 1) .Value is as follows.

{"Req":{"TRBC":0,"TRBC_chain":[""],"aSectors":[{},{},{},{},{}],"markets":[12],"capi_min":0,"capi_max":10,"liqu_min":0,"liqu_max":10,"tri":[0,1,2,3,4,5],"ord":["N","N","N","D","N","N"],"special_option_news":"","special_option_date":"","special_dynamic":"","special_partner":"","result_mode":7,"crit":[],"page":2},"bJSON":"true"}

parameters is as follows.

https://www.marketscreener.com/outils/mods_a/moteurs_results.php?ResultMode=7&model=3&

I do not know what is wrong. I am a beginner in VBA and would appreciate your specific modification.

---

```
Dim MyntraClient As New RestClient
MyntraClient.BaseUrl = "https://www.marketscreener.com/"

'With inline JSON
Dim json As String

 json = Sheets (1) .Cells (2, 1) .Value

Dim Response As RestResponse

Set Response = MyntraClient.PostJSON ("stock-exchange / shares / North-America-8 / United States-12 /

'It's no fun creating json string by hand, instead of create it via Dictionary / Collection / Array

Dim SearchParameters As New Dictionary

SearchParameters.Add "TRBC", 0
SearchParameters.Add "TRBC_chain", Array ("")
SearchParameters.Add "aSectors", Array ("{}", "{}", "{}", "{}", "{}"
SearchParameters.Add "markets", Array (12)
SearchParameters.Add "capi_min", 0
SearchParameters.Add "capi_max", 10
SearchParameters.Add "liqu_min", 0
SearchParameters.Add "liqu_max", 10
SearchParameters.Add "tri", Array (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) '"[0,1,2,3,4,5]"
SearchParameters.Add "ord", Array ("N", "N", "N", "D", "N" N "", "" D "", "" N "", "" N ""] "
SearchParameters.Add "special_option_news", "" ""
SearchParameters.Add "special_option_date", "" ""
SearchParameters.Add "special_dynamic", "" ""
SearchParameters.Add "special_partner", "" ""
SearchParameters.Add "result_mode", 7
SearchParameters.Add "crit", Array ()
SearchParameters.Add "page", 1
SearchParameters.Add "bJSON", True

Set Response = MyntraClient.PostJSON ("outils / mods_a / moteurs_results.php? ResultMode = 7 & model = 3 &", Array (SearchParameters))

'Check status, received content, or do something with the data directly
Debug.Print Response.StatusCode
Debug.Print Response.Content
Sheets (1) .Cells (3, 1) .Value = Response.StatusCode
Sheets (1) .Cells (4, 1) .Value = Response.Content
```

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8is3H.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used fiddler to monitor the web traffic when making that page selection from the landing page (page2). I used that info to generate an XMLHTTP Post request.

I put the following in sheet 1 cell A1 to save on escaping characters in the code.

```
{"TRBC":0,"TRBC_chain":[""],"aSectors":[{},{},{},{},{}],"markets":[12],"capi_min":0,"capi_max":10,"liqu_min":0,"liqu_max":10,"tri":[0,1,2,3,4,5],"ord":["N","N","N","D","N","N"],"special_option_news":"","special_option_date":"","special_dynamic":"","special_partner":"","result_mode":7,"crit":[],"page":2}
```

Then used the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable
    Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, body As String, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    body = "Req=" & ws.Range("A1")
    body = body & "&bJSON=true"

    With http
        .Open "POST", "https://www.marketscreener.com/outils/mods_a/moteurs_results.php?ResultMode=7&model=3&undefined, False"
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send body
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set hTable = .getElementById("ZBS_restab_2b")
    End With
    WriteTable hTable, 2, ws
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    r = startRow
    With ws
        Set tRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each tr In tRow
            r = r + 1
            Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            c = 1
            For Each td In tCell
                .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText
                c = c + 1
            Next td
        Next tr
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Sample results:**

[image]

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library
2. Microsoft XML, V6.0 'For my Excel 2016 version

Comment: Another great xmlhttp answer.

Comment: QHarr..Thanks a lot..Sometimes, however, a runtime error occurs in Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName ("th"). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please see updated code. Any problems, please give me the failing jJSON string in A1.

Comment: I found the function to create a json string on the Internet. So, a1 of sheet1 is changed to sheet2! Aa2, and each key and value is inserted into each cell, and it is connected by function function

Comment: Ok, but how does that reflect on my answer to your original question? For the example you gave my code works I believe.  Do you have a different string which is failing? Or is the failure due to this looping?

Comment: If the above answer is correct and this is about a different implementation problem then asking a new question is going to be the best and easiest place to answer it.

Comment: I think it is probably my mistake. Because when I first applied the coding that QHarr sent me, I think it worked wonderfully well. The reason why I have a problem is because I asked to post to the homepage many times a day, so I thought that I might have blocked it on my homepage. So I asked QHarr about this again. However, QHarr says there is no problem with the code, so let's try to solve the problem yourself. I am a student in business administration. I am interested in programming language. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you post a new question explaining the new problem, perhaps including the function and expected results I would be happy to help. If the problem is coming from unseen code then that needs to go into the new question. Explain how this looping works and on what part of the loop it fails. I have made no comment on whether you are blocked from accessing the page. If you inspect the responseText from the HTTPRequest you should be able to investigate this. Or use a tool like POSTMAN to issue and inspect the webtraffic.

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I do not know, but I guess the cause of 91error is because sResponse appears as 0 # - #. I also checked the HTML Object and XML v6.0, and the Excel I am using is the 2016 version. And as QHarr originally told me, the sheet1! A1 value was restored as a jSON string. Then I tried to run but ..sResponse is 0 # _ #. So a little embarrassing. QHarr's reply is that it worked well.

Comment: This is with the same string in A1 as per the question?

Comment: At first, QHarr showed me that it worked fine, but after running it a few times now, 0 # _ # continues to come out.

Comment: The entire response text: can you pastebin a link to it here?

Comment: pastebin..? maybe is this..?

  0#-#

  <link href="css/nservices.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <div class="ns_MS_FDpopup">

        <div style="width: 650px; background-color: #ffffff; display: inline-block; margin-top: 30%;">

          <div class="ns_entete_popup ">Stock Screener</div>

            <div class=" ns_center" style=" padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px"><img src="/images/nservices/ns_exclamation_tease.svg" style="width: 50px" alt="!"/></div>

Comment: <div class="ns_Txt16 ns_center">You've reached the free usage limit of the Stock Screener. <br>

            Sign up for a free membership to continue your search</div>

            <div></div>

            <div class=" ns_pad20 ns_center" ><a href="/prov.php?prov=2017_interne&ref=marketscreener_limit&url=%2Fregistration%2Fmember%2F"><div class="ns_btAbo ns_colorBlue">New member</div></a><div class="ns_btLogin" style="margin-left: 20px;" onclick="$(window).scrollTop(0);activTopSmenu(1);">Log in</div></div>

        </div>

    </div>

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ .And yes, you can see in the text it is saying: "You've reached the free usage limit of the Stock Screener" -  which may be the current problem. I don't know what the limit is. I did get this message once but not since I switched to a POST request as given in my answer. Does it offer an API? Or you can switch to using Selenium and passing your credentials to login and then scrape. Additionally, there is [this](http://blog.intrinio.com/stock-screener-api-intrinio/).

Comment: It seems.. limit on that homepage. QHarr is kind enough to explain it well enough. thanks a lot..I am a beginner who knows only a little about excel. So VBA is a bit of a treat, but other programming languages do not have the ability to handle it. kkkk .. If I want to solve this problem, I am trying to use ie.navigate with CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.Application"), not intrinio. Could it solve the problem if I coded to recognize the cookie during the operation and proceeded to work ... or do I have a similar problem like this?

Comment: I would use [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic) and pass the  login information via code. I assume if you have a login that cookie setting is not required. I am not sure what you mean by limit on hompage? You can still access p2 onwards?

Comment: limit on that homepage....that means free usage limit of the stock screener...I searched the Selenium basic you gave me a little on the internet. It seems to be a useful program if you can use it well. Though I do not have time to study because of a little time now .. I will study later in time. Thank you for your sincere advice.

Comment: No worries. Selenium is very easy.